# LCD monitor runs for second or two and then becomes black

Tags: lcd

I have Samsung SyncMaster 923NW LCD monitor.

1. When I turn my PC on:
   - I get image on the screen for a second or two and then it becomes black.
2. If I turn off and then turn this monitor back on while PC is running:
   - I see my desktop for a second or two only and again nothing but black.
3. If I disconnect its data cable from PC:
   - I get the "no signal" massage for a second or two and turn black with green led still on all the time.

Comment: If you're using a HDMI cable, could you try another HDMI cable? or if you're PC has alternative video connectors, could you try DVI/VGA?

Comment: Haven't you setup an unsupported resolution? What is your OS?

Comment: You need to isolate the problem to the computer, cable, or monitor. Does the monitor work properly on another computer?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of connections are you using?
HDMI, DVI, VGA?
Try another cable or connection type.

Any chance you can try another monitor?
If it works I would advise you to update your graphic card drivers.
I know it's not possible right now if you don't see anything on the screen.